# How do I create a Joomla blog with a set word count instead of readmore?

Tags: joomla, blogs

I have a module that needs to use its own readmore based on word-count. So I'd like to remove the  from inside the article. Also clients are going to be using this site and I'd like it as simple as possible...

So when I go to a blog menu, I'd just like something that will truncate the blog item view based on word count...

Thnaks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is already a module for you to use in circumstances like this. The K2 Content Module. You can always set word count to the items and many more features. All you need to do is install the K2 Component.